# mongodb how to display Null or none for a field instead of it being blank

Tags: mongodb

The query below will show me the names of people and all their details.  Some have addresses, some have not.  It shows the addresses where they exist.  What do I use if I wanted to show "addresses: "none" " where there are none given?  I am also trying to sort by name.

`db.test.find({name:{$exists:true}}, {_id:0}, {$sort:{"name":1}})`

So far I can select the ones which have names, hide the _id column from view and sort by name.  All the addresses (where they exist) are given. It is the "addresses: none" I am finding tricky.

Any pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test collection with the following documents

```
{"_id" : 1, "name" : "Thyame", "address": "Kapan" },
{"_id" : 2, "name" : "Diple", "address": null },
{"_id" : 3, "name" : "Sid" }
```

and Query is

```
db.test.aggregate 
   (
[
  {
     $project: {
        address: { $ifNull: [ "$address", "Null" ] }
     }
  }
]
);
```